# Initial Value Problem Eigenfunctions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions, initial-value-problems

Given an operator and boundary conditions, there often exist eigenfunctions which allow for Fourier summation solutions.

Is there a similar way to solve initial value problems, for example,

$$
\partial_t^2 \psi = s(t) \\
\text{s.t.  } \psi(0) = 0 \\
\psi'(0) = 0
$$

Can I find functions that are eigen-functions satisfying the initial conditions? They can be eigen-functions under any inner product.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, just information in case other students find this confusing like me.

$$
\partial_t^2 \psi = \lambda \psi
$$
can be Laplace transformed as, (with some algebra done)

$$
(s^2 - \lambda)\tilde{\psi} = s \psi(0) + \psi'(0) \\
\tilde{\psi} = \frac{s \psi(0) + \psi'(0)}{s^2 - \lambda}
$$

Thus there are clearly conditions of the initial conditions for non-trivial solutions.

What I personally found to satisfy my search is that I can form Green's functions via the Laplace transform by solving,

$$
\hat{L} \psi = \delta(t - t_0)
$$

and using the Laplace transform properties to handle the initial conditions.